# Can't I form an array in a for-loop to echo the current count? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, loops, output, echo

I am trying to echo the current element of an array, which are called in a function.

This is what I tried:

```
function funktion($a, ...$params)
  {
      echo $a . "<br>";

      $elemente = count($params);

      for ($i = 0; $i <= $elemente; $i++)
      {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        {
          echo $elemente[$i] . "<br>";
        }
      }
  }

  funktion("Hier kommt etwas Text:", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

But the output are only the `<br>` elements. It's 5 `<br>` elements and that's the right count, but why does it not show the current number in the loop?

This is how it worked, but I still want to know, what I did wrong.

Working code:

```
function funktion($a, ...$params)
      {
      echo $a . "<br>";

      $elemente = count($params);

      for ($i = 0; $i <= $elemente; $i++)
      {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
        {
          echo $i . "<br>";
        }
      }
  }

  funktion("Hier kommt etwas Text:", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

So, in the working code I just changed from echo'ing `$elemente[$i]` to just the `$i`. I don't get, why I can't output the array element.

Comment: `$elemente` is just a number: the number of elements in the array. The actual array is called `$params`, so you should be echo'ing `$params[$i]`. If you get the correct result by echo'ing `$i`, that's accidental: `$i` is the *index* of the array, not the array entry *at* that index.

Comment: Mhh using $params[$i] doesn't output anything, not even the break-elements.

Comment: It should: https://3v4l.org/odbZF -- note that I did need to change `<=` to `<` in the for loop to get rid of an undefined offset notice for the last item.

Comment: Oh right! It was my bad, I used "()" instead of []. Thanks for your quick help! :)